# How can fzf's command history search always be shown, automatically and without CTRL-R?

Tags: command-line, shell, autocomplete, command-history

With fzf you can press `CTRL-R` to have a command history search box shown below the prompt and fuzzy search. I want it shown automatically for each new prompt, without having to press `CTRL-R`.